# Difference between "how do I get to" and "how can I get to"

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I'm struggling with these questions. 
What's the difference between them?

Comment: How do I convince you there's no significant difference? *Can* I convince you? *Do* I convince you?

Comment: 'Can I' literally means "Am I able to". So if you want to be grammatically correct, do not use can. "Can I do this?" Means: "Am I  able to do this?" "Can I get to the station from here?" Means: "Am I  able to get there from here?" However, in real, everyday English -- it's the same and there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions are essentially equivalent.  The nuance might be that "do" may be interpreted as asking for specific step in *doing* an action, whereas "can" may be interpreted as asking *how* to do something (ability)

> How **do** I get to the library?
>
> Go down to the corner. Turn right. Walk a half mile and it will be on your left.

whereas

> How **can** I get to the library?
>
> You can either walk, drive, or take the bus, the library is very accessible.

Answer (score 1):

In casual conversation, when dealing with directions and travel, they are equivalent.

Without anything else, they have an implied meaning of "from here". Otherwise, you should specify "from ..."

> How can I get to the library?
>
> How do I get to the library?
>
> How can I get to your office from the train station?
>
> How can I get from the train station to your office?
>
> How do I get to the museum from here?
>
> How do I get from here to the museum?

If you are talking about something other than directions, they are also equivalent.

> How can I get my passport renewed?
>
> How do I get my passport renewed?